# Best practice for passing callbacks to deeply nested functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a deeply nested node js function structure, what is the best way to pass a callback to a deep layer? I've got about 4 layers here and it's starting to get out of hand, and polluting the function signatures.

generic.js

```
function dumpProcessor(dump, callbacks) {
    var listing = callbacks.getPropertySelector(dump);
    callbacks.transformListingToProperty(listing);
}

function processDumps(dumps, callbacks){
    console.log('process dumps');
    dumpProcessor(dumps, callbacks)
}

function gotTheDumps(agent, dumps, callbacks){
    endDateProperties(agent, function(){
        processDumps(dumps, callbacks);
    });
}
```

specific.js

```
function getPropertySelector() {}
function transformListingToProperty() {}

var callbacks = {
    "agent": "agent",
    "getPropertySelector": getPropertySelector,
    "transformListingToProperty": transformListingToProperty
};

abc.getDumps("AGENT", generic.gotTheDumps, callbacks);
```

Comment: you shoud take a look to async.js it's module to handle nested calls.

Comment: Don't use callbacks. Go for promises.

Comment: Why is `callbacks` an object and what is it supposed to do? You should use functions as callbacks.

Comment: Callbacks is an object because it allows me to package up the callbacks into one entity and pass that up the chain rather than have every callback as an individual function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is not really the callbacks.  It's the fact that you are passing the same thing several layers deep using function parameters.  This is not an issue specific to callbacks.  This is one of the reasons object-oriented programming was invented.  This is generally avoided by using objects.  The function parameters that appear over and over in numerous method signatures are converted to fields in an object, the functions are converted to methods of the same object.  Then all your methods have access to those fields, you don't have to keep passing them over and over as function arguments.

```
var dumper = {};
dumper.callbacks = callbacks;

dumper.dumpProcessor = function(dump) {
    var listing = this.callbacks.getPropertySelector(dump);
    this.callbacks.transformListingToProperty(listing);
 };
```

call it like this:

```
dumper.dumpProcessor(someDump);
```